# How to use UNIX_TIMESTAMP on a whole table?

Tags: mysql, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I've been using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in my DB for entries, but now wish to change to unix timestamp instead.

As seen here I have the data, but for each row I want to use UNIX_TIMESTAMP() and the value it returns to be placed in the unixtime column.

[image]
I've never messed around with big database changes and would appreciate a response.

Answer (score 0):

I found it out myself by manipulating another post but doing it vice-versa.

```
UPDATE t_records SET unixtime = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timeSet);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might not able to replace the same column with unix_time, You will have to add another column first and set the values there. Later you can rename the columns.

```
alter table T add unix_time BIGINT(14);
update T set unix_time = unix_timestamp(<old_time_column>);
alter table T drop <old_time_column>;
alter table T change unix_time <old_time_column> BIGINT(14);
```